# Is the Game of the Year version of Fable 2 as buggy as the standard version?

Tags: version-differences, fable-2

I had *Fable 2* for Xbox 360 (PAL version, i.e. Europe/Australia) and it was buggy as hell. If I was married, my wife would go from totally happy to leaving me in an instant. There were several other minor glitches that annoyed me. I traded in the game because I got sick of the bugs.

Does anyone know if the GOTY version does anything to fix these annoyances? If so I might pick it up on the cheap to tide me over until *Fable 3*...

Comment: "If I was married, my wife would go from totally happy to leaving me in an instant." - and why would it be wrong in game? This is how it works in real life too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's probably just the PAL version. I've played through the NTSC one, and saw no problems at all - nor have I heard of any problems from others who have played it.

Chances are you're going to see the same types of bugs between the original edition and the GotY edition, simply due to the fact that GotY will only include the new/downloadable content that's been made available since the original's release.

If you can't play using another region code, then you could try the game on a different console, and see if the bugs propagate.

Answer (score 2):

I have the GOTY version (PAL) and I havent faced any issues so far. I have completed the main quest and now working on some side quests. My wife did leave me (and my child was taken away by some agency) but that's because I was too busy buying and selling real estate.

Comment: Oh wait. I remember... my wife didn't leave me; she died.

Comment: nominated for husband of the year award